# Tensorflow: Tuning rules of quantization

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is there a way that the following process:
https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization

And the call:
`tf.contrib.quantize.create_eval_graph()`

Could be tuned in such way like the following call does?

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/quantize

I would like to have the weights being scaled to 8bits with symmetric ranges, with exact 0 and max/min being power 2 like it's with the **SCALED** mode. For example I would prefer -31 to 31 instead of -10 to 30. Even when -10 to 30 would give better resolution at 8bits, but accurate 0, symmetricity and range as power of 2 is more important for DSP devices.

Answer (score 0):

TOCO(tf.lite.TocoConverter) so far does not have the option to control quantization type since you actually want symmetric quantization instead of asymmetric approach. However, real value of 0.0 is guaranteed to be [accurate](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cb5f4b3f553bbae29e45561476ce2fa54654bd9a/tensorflow/core/kernels/fake_quant_ops_functor.h#L79) during quantization. This means 0.0 is mapped to an uint8 q without any rounding error.